# Heap corruption in deconstructor

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program for decompiling some game script files. The latest part I've added is giving me some errors when dealing with dynamic arrays. This is the offending code:

```
typedef struct _COD9_ANIMREF_1
{
    DWORD name;
    DWORD reference;
};

typedef struct _COD9_USEANIM_1
{
    WORD name; // offset of name
    WORD numOfReferences; // reference count
    WORD numOfAnimReferences; // reference count
    WORD null1; // always null
    DWORD* references = NULL; // dynamic array of references, amount = numOfReferences
    _COD9_ANIMREF_1* animReferences = NULL; // dynamic array of references, amount = numOfAnimReferences
    ~_COD9_USEANIM_1()
    {
        if (references)
            delete[] references;
        if (animReferences) // program officially breaks here, if continued causes heap corruption
            delete[] animReferences;
    }
};
typedef struct _COD9_WORK_1
{
    _COD9_GSC_1 Hdr;
    char* data = NULL;
    int* includes = NULL;               //done
    _COD9_USEANIM_1* usingAnim = NULL;  //not done, heap corruption
    _COD9_STRING_1* strings = NULL; //done
    _COD9_FUNC_1* functions = NULL; //done
    _COD9_EXTFUNC_1* extFunctions = NULL; //done
    _COD9_RELOC_1* relocations = NULL;  //done
    ~_COD9_WORK_1()
    {
        if (data)
            delete[] data;
        if (includes)
            delete[] includes;
        if (usingAnim)
            delete[] usingAnim;
        if (strings)
            delete[] strings;
        if (functions)
            delete[] functions;
        if (extFunctions)
            delete[] extFunctions;
        if (relocations)
            delete[] relocations;
    }
};
if (tstg.Hdr.numOfUsinganimtree)
{
    tstg.usingAnim = new _COD9_USEANIM_1[tstg.Hdr.numOfUsinganimtree];
    igsc.seekg(tstg.Hdr.usinganimtreeStructs);
    for (int i = 0; i < tstg.Hdr.numOfUsinganimtree; i++)
    {
        _COD9_USEANIM_1 anim;
        igsc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&anim.name), sizeof(anim.name));
        igsc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&anim.numOfReferences), sizeof(anim.numOfReferences)); // this is 0 in this instance
        igsc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&anim.numOfAnimReferences), sizeof(anim.numOfAnimReferences));
        igsc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&anim.null1), sizeof(anim.null1));
        anim.references = new DWORD[anim.numOfReferences]; // allocate 0 size array so theres something to delete
        if(anim.numOfReferences) // should not be entered
        {
            igsc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&anim.references), (anim.numOfReferences*sizeof(DWORD))); // if numOfReference = 0, function should return
        }
        anim.animReferences = new _COD9_ANIMREF_1[anim.numOfAnimReferences];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < anim.numOfAnimReferences; ii++)
        {
            _COD9_ANIMREF_1 animref;
            igsc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&animref.name), sizeof(animref.name));
            igsc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&animref.reference), sizeof(animref.reference));
            anim.animReferences[i] = animref;
        }
        tstg.usingAnim[i] = anim;
        printf("anim: %d\n", i); // program reaches this
    }
    printf("Anims Done\n"); // program doesn't reach this
    ReorderUsingAnim(&tstg);
}
```

Here is what is being read into the fields:

```
anim.name = 0x06BB
anim.numOfReferences = 0x0000
anim.numOfAnimReferences = 0x0001
anim.null1 = 0x0000
```

Where I think the error occurs is with the references array, since technically the size is 0 in this instance. But I'm not sure what to do about it, and I'm pretty lost in general about heap corruptions too.

Comment: Stop using arrays and use `std::vector`.

Comment: You have lots of `if(membervar) delete[] membervar` statements. These all assume that the variable defaults to null if it hasn't been allocated, but I don't see any constructors that initialize them.

Comment: And since this is C++, there is no need for `typedef struct`.  That is a holdover from `C` and not needed in C++.  All you need is `struct`

Comment: @Barmar understood, and added but still having the same issue

Comment: `I'm pretty lost in general about heap corruptions `  -- Stop using constructs that bring on heap corruption.  Use `std::vector` instead of `new[] / delete[]` and that will take away most, if not all of the heap corruption issues away.

Comment: You need to clarify the question. What error are you getting? What makes you think it's in this code? When you have heap corruption, it can leave time bombs that cause errors in totally unrelated code.

Comment: Google "the rule of three".

Comment: Also, don't start your names with underscores.

Comment: @Barmar understood, and added but still having the same issue.

Comment: @drescherjm When the program breaks, there is no error, it just says that it hit a breakpoint when there is none, if I continue then there is a heap corruption. Also I tried putting that in the following if statement but it didn't help anything.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's no way we can tell what you're doing wrong from the snippet you've provided.

Comment: @user1425470 I don't see anything added to the question. What do you mean? You already said earlier that you added the initializations, what did you add the second time?

Comment: @Barmar forgot to add it to the post. added now

Comment: Does that even compile? I don't think you can put default initializations in a struct declaration like that.

Comment: Your `typedef` statements are missing the name of the type they're defining. It's supposed to be `typedef struct XXX { ... } XXX_t;`. But as someone else pointed out, you don't need `typedef` for structures in C++, it's only needed in C.

Comment: @Barmar Visual C++ allows it, and after inspecting it further, it does set them to null on initialization.

Comment: Ahh, clang tells me it's a C++-11 extension.

Comment: @user1425470 The program will fall flat on its face if any copying or assignment is done with those `structs` that have pointers in them, all due to no user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator being implemented.  Another plus for `std::vector` usage, as you wouldn't need these functions written if you used vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_COD9_USEANIM_1` (why oh why newbies use such horrible names??  Is it enjoyable for them to call variables something like _Z_ASHD532___8AHQ_ ??) has two arrays (why not vectors??), `references` and `anim_references`.  It has a destructor which frees the arrays if the pointers are not zero.  **But no constructor.**  This is DANGEROUS.  You should, as a very least, provide a constructor which initializes them `references` and `anim_references` to zero.  You also need the copy constructor.  Remember the rule: if you provide one of the three (default constructor, destructor, copy constructor), you almost certainly need all three.

Ok, now you start your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < tstg.Hdr.numOfUsinganimtree; i++)
```

In the loop you declare the variable `anim`

```
_COD9_USEANIM_1 anim;
```

You allocate its `references` and `animReferences`

```
anim.references = new DWORD[anim.numOfReferences];
...
anim.animReferences = new _COD9_ANIMREF_1[anim.numOfAnimReferences];
```

Finally you copy it to `tstg.usingAnim`

```
tstg.usingAnim[i] = anim;
```

You know what happens when you copy it?  All fields are just copied.  So now `references` and `animReferences` of `tstg.usingAnim[i]` point to the same address as `references` and `animReferences` of anim.

And then, the block ends.  The evil computer calls the destructor for `anim`.  The destructor calls delete[] for `anim.references` and `anim.animReferences`.  But, `references` and `animReferences` of `tstg.usingAnim[i]` point to the same adresses.  In other words, they now point to the array which were deleted.

Now the behaviour of your heap is unpredictable.

The best suggestion: forget arrays, and use vectors. You know, `std::vector` from the standard library.

Second best suggestion: provide default constructor and copy constructor. (PS: and assignment operator!)

(Note that you program may have other bugs too.)

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about it like that. I would prefer not to get into vectors though, so I will look into the copy constructor asap. If it doesn't work then I guess I'll have no choice. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: The rule of 3 is not for **default constructor**, copy constructor, and destructor. It's for the copy constructor, destructor, and **assignment operator**.

Comment: Ok, its true. But in this case, default constructor should be implemented too.

Comment: To the original poster: you should also implement the assignment operator.  James Adkison is right.